# Create new union case from existing one

Tags: f#

Is there a better way to write the `addValues` function below? It seems it should be possible to use pattern matching rather than FSharp.Reflection but I can't see it.

```
open System
open FSharp.Reflection

type Value =
    | Tag1 of decimal
    | Tag2 of decimal
    | Error of string

let addValues v1 v2 =
    let c1, f1 = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(v1, v1.GetType())
    let c2, f2 = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(v2, v2.GetType())
    let amt1 = (f1.[0]) :?> decimal
    let amt2 = (f2.[0]) :?> decimal

    if c1 = c2
        then ((FSharpValue.MakeUnion(c1, [|box (amt1 + amt2)|]))) :?> Value
        else Error "Mixed Tags"
```

This can be used like so:

```
addValues (Tag1 22m) (Tag1 10m) //Value = Tag1 32M
addValues (Tag1 22m) (Tag2 10m) //Value = Error "Mixed Tags"
```

Comment: What should happen with `addValues (Error "e1") (Error "e2")`?

Comment: are you sure that you need `Error` in this type?

Comment: just for me in this case better to use [`Choice<'T1,'T2>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.choice%5B%27t1%2C%27t2%5D-union-%5Bfsharp%5D) or maybe `Option`

Comment: Example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/SpF502

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear how `addValues (Error "e1") (Error "e2)` should be handled but for the other cases you can do:

```
let addValues v1 v2 =
    match v1, v2 with
    | Tag1 d1, Tag1 d2 -> Tag1 (d1 + d2)
    | Tag2 d1, Tag2 d2 -> Tag2 (d1 + d2)
    | Error e1, Error e2 -> //???
    | _ -> Error "Mixed Tags"
```

Comment: I should have specified "without enumerating all the tags in the match". Basically I want to check if the two cases are are the same and if so return a new one with the sum. Otherwise return an error. As for if the two values are errors in that case returning either error is fine in my domain.

Answer (score 4):

This is not precisely what the original question was about, but - as some other commenters - I have a hunch that your datatypes are not really well chosen. Having an `Error` case means that, the moment you have more tags, your `addValues` function becomes really awkward. If I assume that all your values are decimal, you could re-define as follows:

```
type Tag = | Tag1 | Tag2
type ResultOrError = | Result of Tag * decimal | Error of string
```

(or use one of the `Choice` types). `addValues` then becomes:

```
let addValues t1 t2 = 
    match t1, t2 with
    | Result (tag1, v1), Result (tag2, v2) when tag1 = tag2 -> Result (tag1, v1 + v2)
    | Result _, Result _ -> Error "Tag mismatch"
    | Result _, Error _ -> failwith "not implemented"
    | Error _, _ -> failwith "not implemented"
```

The moment you extend your tags type to `type Tag = | Tag1 | Tag2 | Tag3`, `addValues` remains still working.

Comment: Indeed this is an alternate design I've been playing with. It is just a bit more verbose rather than writing `Tag1 33m` to create a value you need to write `Result(Tag1, 33m)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to blow the same trumpet as [Anton Schwaighofer in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124493/2807130). The crucial piece of information has to be inside the data structure, because this will leverage monad techniques to do [the lifting](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lifting); also you would otherwise need separate calls to the constructors of the cases `Tag1` and `Tag2`.

```
type Tag = Tag1 | Tag2
type ResultOrError = 
| Result of Tag * decimal
| Error of string

let bind2 f = function
| Result(tag, value) -> f tag value
| error -> error
let lift2EqualTag op mx my =
    bind2 (fun tagX x ->
        bind2 (fun tagY y ->
            if tagX = tagY then Result(tagX, op x y)
            else Error "Mixed tags" ) my ) mx
let add = lift2EqualTag (+)

add (Result(Tag1, 22m)) (Result(Tag1, 10m))
// val it : ResultOrError = Result (Tag1,32M)
add (Result(Tag1, 22m)) (Result(Tag2, 10m))
// val it : ResultOrError = Error "Mixed tags"
```